# Basic Implementation Idea in Java

Tags: java, message-queue

I am not asking for the entire code here. I need an idea and optimized solution for a task. Please provide an idea how to implement:

There are two apps:
1)Series of numbers (creates a series of numbers) and sends to app2 via a distributed queue ( using just a java Queue implementation)
2)Even or odd (returns even or odd)

I want to know how can i send the numbers to app2 as both are different applications.I dont want to use JMS.

Can any one provide an idea or similar examples would be really appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need a distributed queue you might consider using Apache Kafka.

Comment: A simple and comprehensive example - https://www.novell.com/documentation/extend5/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/pointToPoint-1.htm

Comment: @bhspencer Thanks for the advice.But i want to use java queue implementation. Ca you please provide an example for that .I have tried that but cant find 1.

Comment: Hi @WasiAhmad. Thanks for the link. is there any example without using JMs please.